# Fbgraph Undefined method search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Fbgraph with my rails application.

I'm not able to call search on my `FBUser` object.

My error is 
undefined method `search' for`#

and my code is

```
<%= @user.facebook.search('a') %>
```

I'm also trying

```
<%= @user.facebook.fetch.search('a') %>
```

The `@user` is an authenticated user and I can make other calls that work

like

```
<% @user.facebook.fetch.home(:q => 'The Grand Social').each do |f| %>
```

but that call only searches the feed.  I'm hoping to search only the authenticated users status updates.  It should be

```
<% @user.facebook.fetch.posts(:q => 'The Grand Social').each do |f| %>
```

but that returns nothing.

Documentation says that I should be able to use it ---

```
FbGraph::User.search('fb_graph', :access_token => ACCESS_TOKEN)
```

any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Provide code please. Also, you know you need to register your app with Facebook to get your access token, right?

Answer (score 1):

Look at this guy's tutorial to set up fb_graph:

http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~liuisaac/site/blog/201009/ror-and-facebook-with-fb-graph.html

Then, you should be able to make calls like:

```
user = FbGraph::User.fetch('dylandrop');
```

Note that for most calls, however, you need to be given access to the information, i.e., people need to add your app.